# Apply common css to text of all the child elements of body

Tags: jquery

I want to select text from all the tags (p, heading, span, label, div ) that are within the body tag in HTML and apply a common css.

To that I am trying the following which gives me the result but when I logged the result I found that the loop run 3 times. I can't figure out why.

```
$('body').children().each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text())
    $(this).css('color','red');
})
```

```
<body>
        <div id="test-text">
        ALL TEXT
        <p>sample text</p>
        <p>sample text2</p>
        <span>sample text3</span>
        <h1>sample text3</h1>
        <label>sample text4</label>
</body>
```

How to fix this? Or is there any better alternative ?

**EDIT** The reason I cannot directly apply color red in the css file inside the body is because I need to do certain manipulations by selecting all the text values inside body for which I need to loop. This is just a sample of the actual problem. Besides, $('body').children().text().css('color','red') gives me error.

I just want to understand why it loops three times.

Comment: A better alternative way is adding css style `body { color: red; }`

Comment: You're missing closing `</div>` - can you provide a snippet with the same code that you run to get "the loop runs 3 times"?

Comment: @DavidJawHpan The reason I cannot directly apply color red in the css file inside the body is because I need to do certain manipulations by selecting all the text values inside body for which I need to loop. This is just a sample of the actual problem. Besides, $('body').children().text().css('color','red') gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to change a text color for all the child elements, I would set the css `color` property to the parent element and all the children would inherit the property. Example - In your case, you can set

```
  body{
    color: red;
  }
```

Alternative to this, you can use `>` to select all the children.

```
  body>*{
    color:red;
  }
```

Comment: The reason I cannot directly apply color red in the css file inside the body is because I need to do certain manipulations by selecting all the text values inside body for which I need to loop. This is just a sample of the actual problem. Besides, $('body').children().text().css('color','red') gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly apply `css` property instead of iterating all children.
See below code.

Your code is also working fine, just note that you have not closed the first `div` tag which could be the reason for loop is running thrice.

You can make use of CSS class as well and apply it to all children

```js
//$('body').children().css('color','red');
//OR
$('body').children().addClass('red-text');
```

```css
.red-text { color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-text">
ALL TEXT</div>
<p>sample text</p>
<p>sample text2</p>
<span>sample text3</span>
<h1>sample text3</h1>
<label>sample text4</label>
```

Comment: The reason I cannot directly apply color red in the css file inside the body is because I need to do certain manipulations by selecting all the text values inside body for which I need to loop. This is just a sample of the actual problem. Besides, $('body').children().text().css('color','red') gives me error. I just want to understand why it loops 3 times instead of 1.

Comment: The code you have shared is looking fine and not running for 3 times but if you can reproduce the issue on Code snippet or JSFiddle then I can take a look at it and help you

Answer (score 0):

```
body > *{
    color:red;
 }
```

All elements inside the tag body will be applied the rule of css color:red.